# Matrix that transforms the vector components inverse of the matrix that transforms the basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, change-of-basis

I'm starting to learn about tensors and my textbook (Riley, Hobson and Bence, 3rd) states that the matrix that transforms the vector components must be the inverse of the matrix that transforms the basis vectors, without an explanation whatsoever.

If we introduce a set of basis vectors $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3$, then we can describe any vector $\mathbf x$ in terms of its components $x_1, x_2, x_3$ with respect to this basis: $$\mathbf x = x_1 \mathbf e_1+ x_2 \mathbf e_2+ x_3 \mathbf e_3 = x_i\mathbf e_i$$
where we have used the summation convention to write the sum in a more compact form.

If we now introduce a new basis $\mathbf e'_1, \mathbf e'_2,\mathbf e'_3$ related to the old one by
$$\mathbf e'_j = S_{ij}\mathbf e_i$$ where the coefficient $S_{ij}$ is the $i$th component of the vector $\mathbf e'_j$ with respect to the unprimed basis, then we may write $\mathbf x$ with respect to the new basis as  $$\mathbf x = x'_1 \mathbf e'_1+ x'_2 \mathbf e'_2+ x'_3 \mathbf e'_3 = x'_i\mathbf e'_i\ .$$

Now, my question.

> If we denote the matrix with elements $S_{ij}$ by $S$, then the
> components $x_i'$ and $x_i$ in the two bases are related by $$x_i' =
>  (S)^{-1}_{ij}x_j\ .$$

How does it follow that the matrix that transforms the vector components must be the inverse of the matrix that transforms the basis vectors?

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors) Wikipedia article on contravariant vectors says the same, without explanation:

> the matrix that transforms the vector components must be the inverse of the matrix that transforms the basis vectors.

Comment: You may use the equation $e_j'=S_{ij}e_i$ to decompose $x_j$ in base $j$ into base $i$ yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof. By definition, the matrix $S$ satisfies
$$
\mathbf e_i' = S_{ji}\mathbf e_j.
$$
With the definition of the inverse, it follows that
$$
\mathbf e_i = (S^{-1})_{ji} \mathbf e_j'.
$$

With that, we have
$$
\mathbf x = x_j \mathbf e_j = x_j (S^{-1})_{ij}\mathbf e_i' = \left[(S^{-1})_{ij} x_j\right] \mathbf e_i'.
$$
So indeed, $\left[(S^{-1})_{ij} x_j\right]$ is the coefficient of $\mathbf e_i'.$